# jPlayer: playing files from FTP server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ftp, jplayer

Just a quick question; I can't seem to find anything on the web.

I'm looking for a way to use the jQuery jPlayer to play audio files from an FTP server on a different host. It works fine in Chrome, the user is asked to supply login credentials into a Chrome popup, and then the audio plays no problem; Firefox and Explorer fail --- even if I'm logged in to the FTP server in another tab, nothing happens.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Cheers.

Comment: FTP wasn't designed for streaming media so that isn't surprising. Why not HTTP?

Comment: The media is stored in on an external Network Hard Disk; it does not have the capability of HTTP access, just FTP. The FTP port is forwarded from the router to the hard disk.